# How to implement a dynamic dropdown menu in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a web application where I need to create a dropdown menu that dynamically populates its options based on data from the server. I want the dropdown to update and display the available options whenever the user clicks on it.

I have the data available in JSON format, and I know how to fetch it using AJAX. However, I'm unsure about how to dynamically generate the dropdown options using JavaScript and update the menu with the fetched data.

Could someone guide me on the best approach to implement this dynamic dropdown menu in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript? It would be great if you could provide a step-by-step explanation or a code example to help me get started.

Thank you!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not present any effort in resolving the problem, presents no code, and it's most likely created by the Answerer for the sole purpose of attaching an AI generated response.